# C# Serialization limitations

Tags: c#, attributes

i want to implement a general Memento-Pattern in C#. It is working fine but i use the Serializeable() Attribute to do a deep copy of a object. My implementation using generics so if someone use it he has to give his class as type. 
Now the class from user must have the Attribute Serializeable() too. Are there any limitations for a class which using Serializeable()?

In fact:

1. Are there any performance problems?
2. Is it possible to use an interface?
3. Is it possible to use inerhitence?
4. Is it possible to use Auto-Properties?

I dont know how the Attribute works and so iam a bit scary of using this in such a global way.

regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. for small models that you are cloning in memory, not usually
2. irrelevent; when using `[Serializable]` you are typically using `BinaryFormatter` - which looks at the *objects themselves*; it doesn't matter what interfaces they implement - the interfaces *are not used*
3. yes, for the same reason - but all types in the model must be `[Serializable]`
4. yes, for the same reason; note : the default `BinaryFormatter` implementation is looking at fields - it won't even touch the properties

Personally, I try to advise *against* `BinaryFormatter`, but this is perhaps not an unreasonable use. However! Be careful that it is easy to suck extra objects into the model accidentally, must commonly through `event`s. Note that it is a good idea to mark all `event`s as non-serialized:

```
[field:NonSerialized]
public event EventHandler Something;
```

(or apply to the field directly if using explicit `add`/`remove` accessors)

Note also that any members like:

```
public object Tag {get;set;} // caller-defined
```

should also probably be `[field:NonSerialized]`.

Personally, I'd *prefer* a different serializer, but: this will often work. I will say, though: try to avoid *persisting* the output of `BinaryFormatter`, as it is hard to guarantee compatibility between revisions of your code.

> I dont know how the Attribute works

It does *nothing at all* except add an IL flag that says "by the way, consider this ok to be serialized"; actually, most serializers *don't even look at this flag* - but `BinaryFormatter` is one of the few that *do* look at this flag. The real code here is `BinaryFormatter`, which basically does:

- have I seen this object before? if so, store the key only
- what type is it? is it `[Serializable]`? store the type info
- invent a new reference and store that as the identity
- does it have a custom serializer? if so: use that
- what fields does it have? access each in turn and store the name/value pair